# adobe - previous install destination doesn't exist

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

Recently I installed linux alongside Windows 7. After partitioning I'm left with Windows with one partition.

The thing is, I used to have photoshop on partition D, but now despite it not existing Adobe instalator finds it was there, and wants to install it on partition D (which doesn't exist), fails to do so, and quits.

1) How / Where do I remove information about previous instalation? or

2) How do I force Adobe to install where I want it?

Comment: Have you simply tried to uninstall the program and install it again? ( the program being Photoshop ).

Comment: @Ramhound I uninstalled it before I formatted + removed partition D, the info was in windows registry (lucky guess) I found solution in 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Adobe saved this information somewhere in registry files. I found 'CC Cleaner Tool' by Adobe, which cleans all the crap in there:

http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs5-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html

(download at point 3, easy to use - just clear everything)